# Solving the functional $\min \int_0^1y^2y'^2\;dx,\;y(0)=0,\;y(1)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Determine smooth extremums in
>
> $$\min \int_0^1y^2y'^2\;dx,\;y(0)=0,\;y(1)=1$$
>
> by
>
> (a) using the fact that the functional does not contain explicitly
>   variable $x$
>
> (b) applying straightforward the Euler-Lagrange equation

where $y=y(x), \;y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}, \;F(y,y')=y^2y'^2$.

Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right)=0$$

If the integrand does not depend on $x$ then E-L equation gets the form:

$$F-y'F_{y'}=C,$$

where $F_{y'}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$.

I have tried solving this for a while, but I keep getting into complex numbers or into very hairy differential equations. Could someone show me few of the most important steps what to do, where it is easy for me to take on? Thank you for your help!

The (a)-part was more confusing for me. My attempted solution from part (b) was $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$, but I'm not sure of my answer.

P.S. if asked for, I can post my attempts of trying to solve this problem.

Comment: And a third approach is to note that the lower bound $$4\int_0^1 y^2(y')^2\geqslant\left(\int_0^1 2yy'\right)^2=\left(y^2(1)-y^2(0)\right)^2=1,$$ is achieved when Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is an equality, that is, when $2yy'$ is constant, that is, when $y^2(x)=x$ for every $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** Since $F$ does not explicitly depend on $x$ there is a first integral

$$\begin{align} \\
y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} - F &= 2y^{2}y'^{2} - y^{2}y'^{2} \\
&= y^{2}y'^{2} \\
&= C
\end{align}  $$

Rearranging for $y'$ we find

$$y' = \pm \sqrt\frac{C}{y^{2}} $$

Then separating and integrating we get

$$\int y dy = \pm \int C dx \implies \frac{y^{2}}{2} = Cx + D$$

Where $C$ and $D$ are constants. You'll need to use your conditions to solve for the constants.

**b)** If

$$F(y,y') = y^{2}y'^{2}$$

you should get a Lagrange equation of the form

$$\begin{align} \\
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\bigg) - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} &= \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(2y^{2}y'\bigg) -  2yy'^{2} \\
&= (4yy'^{2} + 2y^{2}y'') - 2yy'^{2} \\
&= 0 
\end{align}$$

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you =) yes it does :)

Comment: Hi @Mattos one more question. In $a)$, are we assuming that the constant $C$ in $y'=\pm \sqrt{\frac{C}{y^2}}$ is a positive number? Do we need to make that assumption? If it is negative, then we get into complex numbers in this problem don't we?..

Comment: You don't get into complex numbers because you haven't got conditions to solve for $C$ yet. You need an equation in $y$ not $y'$, that is why you separate and integrate. Then you find the constants $C$ and $D$ using your conditions that $y(0) = 0$ and $y(1) = 1$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for replying =) So $C$ cannot be a complex number? Still not 100% clear. We are saying that the derivative of $y$ is plus or minus of a square root of some number and we we are saying that this number can't be complex because we don't have the conditions yet. Then can we say, that it is real? What can we say about $C$? Can we say anything? Is it possible in some scenario that it would be complex?

Comment: It's just confusing me because, it seems we are treating it like a real number when doing our algebra, but still we don't make any assumptions about it? Thank you for your patience x) I hate uncertainty ;D

Comment: That's alright, it's always hard when you start off. We can't say _anything_ about the constant $C$ until we use our conditions in the equation $\frac {y^{2}}{2} = \pm (Cx + D)$. It doesn't make sense to talk about what $C$ is in the equation $y' = \pm \sqrt \frac{C}{y^{2}}$ because our conditions are for $y$ not $y'$. Hence when we are at the stage where we have an equation for $y'$ we can't determine _anything_ about the constant $C$.

Comment: Aah, I think I got it now :D So it is possible for $C$ to perhaps be a complex number, BUT only if the conditions force it to be, WHEN we have solved for $y$? Right? =) Thank you =)

Comment: Yes, $C$ could be _anything_ at the $y'$ stage, only when you actually apply the conditions at the $y$ stage do you find out what $C$ _really is_. Note that calculus of variations works in both $\mathbb {R}$ and $\mathbb {C}$.